# Visual Studio Express 2012 holding onto Bin directory

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, express, bin

I am having an issue with VSExpress2012 keeping hold of the running exe after I have pressed stop debugging or closed the window.

I am creating a WPF app in C Sharp (my mac doesn't let me put the hash).
To re-run the app, I have to close VS, delete the bin folder, then re-open the solution.

This is super annoying. I was wondering if anyone had come across this and found a decent fix. Not sure if it is VS12 Express or perhaps something else I am overlooking.

---

EDIT:
Just to clarify. I am not wanting to delete the bin directory. This is just my interim solution to allow me to debug the application, because after a run, VS is holding onto the exe and not letting me do another build.

Comment: Check if there is some thread that is running in background

Comment: Very simple app at the moment. No threads created by me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the vshost process that is preventing you removing the folder? E.g. `MyApp.vshost.exe`.

You can probably get away with just deleting the contents of the bin folder except for the file locked by vshost. This is what I do when I want to do a manual clean.

Why do you need/want to delete your bin directory anyway?

Comment: I want to delete the bin directory because when I do another build (/run) of the application after the first one, it says it cannot copy to the output folder because the file is being used by another application (but its actually itself that is holding onto it from the previous run)

Comment: In other words, I don't want to have to delete the bin directory every time, it's just the only way I have at the moment of debugging the application.

Comment: Are there any resources you aren't tidying up? E.g. open files etc in the bin directory?

Comment: No, it is just a very simple app at the moment. No threads or IO operations. (The only questionable thing being the fact that I am using a Winforms host, in order to create a webcam feed. Perhaps this is not handling the file caching correctly for the stream. Its literally just out of the box code though)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what the problem was.

I am using the WPF Webcam control found on CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control)

It seems like this was creating threads internally, which are not getting disposed of correctly. I added some manual scrubbing of the GC to make sure this control gets disposed correctly and presto.

Now, this probably speaks of an underlining problem with that code, but hey ho, my problem is sorted.

Thanks everyone for the input!